# Whats wrong with my simple encryption in C? (cs50 pset 2 - crypt)

Tags: c, cs50

I don't quite understand where these errors are coming from. I am trying to create a simple C program that takes a string and adds an offset to the ASCII value in order to create an extremely simple encryption.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char obscufate_char(char origchar, int offset){
    if(strcmp(origchar, " ") != 0){
        int temp = origchar;
        char newChar = temp + 4;
        return newChar;
    }
    else{
        return 20;
    }
} 

int main(int argc, string argv[]){

    if(argv[1] != NULL){
        string message = argv[1];
    }else{
        printf("%s\n", "Enter a string to encrypt\n");
        string message = GetString();
    }

    if(argv[2] != NULL){
        int offset = atoi(argv[2]);
    }else{
        printf("%s\n", "Enter a offset\n");
        int offset = GetInt();
    }

    printf("%s%s\n", "Your original text is: ", message);
    printf("%s\n", "Your new message is: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++){
        printf("%c\n", obscufate_char(message[i]),offset);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
simple_crypt.c:7:12: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing
      'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &
      [-Werror]
        if(strcmp(origchar, " ") != 0){
                  ^~~~~~~~
                  &
/usr/include/string.h:143:34: note: passing argument to parameter '__s1' here
extern int strcmp (__const char *__s1, __const char *__s2)
                                 ^
simple_crypt.c:20:10: error: unused variable 'message'
      [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
                string message = argv[1];
                       ^
simple_crypt.c:23:10: error: unused variable 'message'
      [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
                string message = GetString();
                       ^
simple_crypt.c:27:7: error: unused variable 'offset' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
                int offset = atoi(argv[2]);
                    ^
simple_crypt.c:30:7: error: unused variable 'offset' [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
                int offset = GetInt();
                    ^
simple_crypt.c:33:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'message'
        printf("%s%s\n", "Your original text is: ", message);
                                                    ^
simple_crypt.c:35:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'message'
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++){
                                  ^
simple_crypt.c:36:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'message'
                printf("%c\n", obscufate_char(message[i]),offset);
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand why those errors are there? Because the compiler is telling you exactly where they are coming from and for that matter it is telling you what it thinks is wrong

Comment: i dont get where the errors are coming from all of the variables seem to be used

Comment: Two hints: the first error is an invalid type, so find out about "pointers and references", the other errors are because you're using variables outside their scope, see "variable scoping rules in c". I'll try and come back when I have a bit more time to put a fuller answer in...

Comment: You misspelled "obfuscate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
simple_crypt.c:7:12: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing
      'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &
      [-Werror]
        if(strcmp(origchar, " ") != 0){
```

You are passing a character when the function expects a char *. origchar is not a char *.

```
simple_crypt.c:20:10: error: unused variable 'message'
      [-Werror,-Wunused-variable]
                string message = argv[1];
```

I'm assuming that cs50.h has a 'string' type for you with this one. You are making an initialization within an if statement and you expect it to be seen outside of the if statement's scope, which is not going to happen. The `message` outside of your if statement is not the same as the `message` inside. The message inside is just declared and initialized but nothing is done with it, essentially making it unused for its scope. To the compiler the message outside the if statement is an undeclared variable.

You should declare `message` outside of the if statements first so the compiler knows that message is and will be created within the scope of main or at least is to be seen outside of the scope of the if statements. You can assign values to it in the if statements, but you shouldn't declare it within an if statement if you expect it to be seen outside of the if statement. The if statement has its own scope and therefore after it is done the `message` you initialized will be gone without doing any operations on it.

same for `offset` and the rest of your `message` errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%c\n", obscufate_char(message[i]),offset);
```

You didn't closed the parentheses correctly. Your function takes two arguments.

```
printf("%c\n", obscufate_char(message[i],offset));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's a syntax error in your `main`:

`printf("%c\n", obscufate_char(message[i]),offset);`

should be, otherwise your whole obscufate_char() would failed

`printf("%c\n", obscufate_char(message[i], offset));`

Secondly, you should declare `message` and `offset` outside an 'if', preferably at the start of your `main`. 
Because declared within an `if` doesn't work outside of it, same goes for declaring `i` in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables before the `if` statements, and then assign values to them in the `if` branches.

```
string message; 
if() 
{
   message = Whatever;
} 
else 
{
   message = SomethingElse;
};
```

The `message` variable declared on line 20 is *not used* if the first `if(argv[1] != NULL)` condition on line 19 is not met.